# Grub Won't Even Come Up after Upgrade to 14.04 Dual Boot Win8

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, 14.04, grub-efi

I'm running a Toshiba Qosmio V1.32002.

I have had a dual-booted Win8/Ubuntu 13.10 traditionally, and I recently upgraded to 14.04.

When I start my computer, the grub bootloader doesn't even pop up and goes straight to starting up Win8. Any idea as to how I could go about bringing my Ubuntu back from the dead here?

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable windows 8 "safe boot" and more like them.
2. You can download and burn boot-repair cd (worked for me) - [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A1st_option_:_get_a_CD_including_Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A1st_option_%3a_get_a_CD_including_Boot-Repair)

Answer (score -2):

I found something that might help.  Look into UEFI options at boot-up from Ubuntu.  Windows 8 requires this option to be turned on in your computer's *TOSHIBA BIOS settings*.  Windows 8 won't boot without it, but there's a [special way to handle it in GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Linux).

You should also try a Boot Repair after you have looked into the [Ubuntu UEFI forums](https://askubuntu.com/tags/grub-efi).

You should also try the *Ubuntu Boot Repair CD*.

Good luck!

I'm sorry I couldn't provide any more links.  Apparently I need to build my reputation before I can. But if you Google the keywords in *Italics* you should be able to find them without a problem.